# How to translate X11 keycode back to scancode or hid usage id reliably

Tags: linux, hid

Almost self resolved.

## Background info

### linux keycode

The below is from: linux_xmodmap_tutorial

- Scancode → a number your keyboard sends to a computer. For USB
  keyboards, it's defined by the USB standard.
- Keycode → a number used by Linux kernel to represent key (or mouse
  button/wheel). The Linux kernel translates scancode to keycode.
- Keysym → a name for a key. keysym is received by X11 applications.

I could be wrong but what `sudo evtest` prints seems like scancode set 1 and since `/dev/input/event*` outputs are similar, at least with my system scancodes and linux keycodes are mostly same.

### X11 keycode

xev command prints keycode and keysym and I observed keycode does not change regardless of keyboard layout I use;qwerty and dvorak layouts produce a different keysym but the same keycode.
Nevertheless, it's not a linux keycode nor hid usage id nor any one of the scancode sets;set1 nor set2 nor set3.

### how is linux keycode generated?

According to arch wiki(I cannot post links):
`/etc/udev/hwdb.bin` translates scancode to keycode.

The Obvious snugs with this are:

1. the wiki says there are non-default *.hwdb files that can be
   compiled to `hwdb.bin`
2. `hwdb.bin` can detect different keyboards and may translates
   a scancode to a keycode differently.

For ubuntu, the only hwdb file I can find is: `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-keyboard-local.hwdb` and that is almost empty. So, by default ubuntu preserves the default scancodes and use them as keycodes I believe.

### How is X11 keycode generated

Some hacker left us a clue here:https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/index.html
The scancode to keycode mapping rule files(which one is being used is the question) are under: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes`

`setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` prints

```
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
```

so, the above files should be controlling the loading behavior for Xkb(Linux changes a lot, so should not expect the same in the future though).

Example:
setxkbmap -print -verbose 10

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,us
variant:    dvp,
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us(dvp)+us:2+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(dvp)+us:2+inet(evdev)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
```

A section in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev` which is likely controlling the keycode file loading behaviour:

```
! model         =       keycodes
  pc98          =       evdev(pc98)
  applealu_jis  =       evdev+macintosh(jisevdev)
  olpc          =       evdev+olpc(olpc)
  olpcm         =       evdev+olpc(olpcm)
  *             =       evdev

! layout[1]     =       keycodes
  $azerty       =       +aliases(azerty)
  $qwertz       =       +aliases(qwertz)
  *             =       +aliases(qwerty)
```

#### My guess

XServer looks at the keyboard's vendor id and device id and applies different rules for translating scancode to keycode.

#### Can I get scancode from X11 keycode?

`xkb/keycodes/evdev` seems to be used as translation rule for most keyboards, using it might does the trick.

#### Is it reliable?

No
The traditional X11 the core protocol does not provide the vendor id nor device id of the keyboard that generated a keyboard event.

### Potential solution?

XI2 - The X Input Extension 2.x
https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/inputproto/XI2proto.txt

```
A RawEvent provides the information provided by the driver to the
client. RawEvent provides both the raw data as supplied by the driver and
transformed data as used in the server.
```

#### Now I have tried RawKeyPress

I could not extract hid usage id nor scancode;though maybe I just overlooked them.
[Capture XI2 RawKeyPress event and interpreting it with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809046/capture-xi2-rawkeypress-event-and-interpreting-it-with-python/45847216#45847216)